# How to add title to a pie chart in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, charts

I understand that there is no title attribute for [apex:pieSeries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pieSeries.htm) so is there any other way to display a title for a pie chart? (besides using html tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, even after taking a look at [Quicklook at visual charting](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2011/09/introducing-visualforce-charting.html) titles aren't used:

```
<apex:page controller="PieChartController" title="Pie Chart">
    <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="{!pieData}">
        <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/>
        <apex:legend position="right"/>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Or as you mention, the attribute doesn't even exist. what is wrong with using html tags? (it all comes down to html in the end anyways)

Comment: Nothing, just wanted to know if there is an alternative or not.